# Hide only specific workbook without affecting other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Already circled the internet and has the same answer that did not work as I wanted to be.

Q: How to hide workbook and show userform without hiding other workbook?

This code is good but hides other workbooks.

```
Application.Visible = False
```

This code is bad as it still shows the excel application.

```
Workbooks("Workbook Name.xlsm").Window(1).Visible = False
```

Also dont work.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Visible = False
```

Lastly, the tool method, going to tools>options>general tab>ignore other application. I dont have this option on my VBA

This is the code I used.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
If Application.Windows.Count > 1 Then
Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
Else
Application.Visible = False
End If
```

and in ThisWorkbook module

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: You ask to hide a specific workbook, but complain it does not hide the application, but also say hiding the appkication is not good as it hides other workbooks... What di you really want? You need to be clear.

Comment: as the title says, hide the only specific workbook. 1st code hides all workbook, then 2nd code did not hide the excel application.

Comment: You state “this code is bad as it still shows the application”, therefore that does not match with your title question...

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to hide one specific workbook is

```
Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
```

where `ThisWorkbook.Name` can be replaced with the desired workbook name like `"MyWb.xlsm"`.

- If there are more than one workbooks open at the same time this will hide the specified workbook (and its application window).
- If this is the only workbook that is open it will hide the specified workbook (**without its application window**).

If you want to hide the application window you must use

```
Application.Visible = False
```

The trick is now to combine them

```
If Application.Windows.Count > 1 Then 'more than one workbook open: Hide workbook only
    Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Visible = False
Else 'only one workbook open: Hide application
    Application.Visible = False
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your kind answer. I try the code, put it in Initialize event and add userform1.show in workbook_open. I open extra workbook then open my working file and did not hide any workbook on the other hand I try to open my working file first before other workbook, other workbook did not shown up.

Comment: The code should work (I'm not sure what you did wrong). Especially if we don't see how your actual code looks like. Edit your original question, add the code you use and describe exactly what you did. Comments are too short to clarify this question.

Comment: Hi, I edit the question and show the code I used. Or should I put the code you gave to ThisWorkbook module?

Comment: Probably the issue is that the code tries to hide the workbook before it is shown. This could be a timing issue. Maybe try to put it into the `UserForm_Activate`.

Comment: how I will use UserForm_Activate?

Comment: Tried. When working file is open I cannot open other workbook, when another workbook is already open then open working file all of workbooks are stuck.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. Sorry, I cannot help you. All I can say is, the code works like I said if eg used on a button.